# ASP.NET glyphicon hyperlink not displaying when using https

Tags: asp.net, .net, https, iis-8, glyphicons

I have the below inline code on my asp.net masterpage which is used to display a glyphicon in the sites navbar to the user if they are in the Admin or SysAdmin roles, and hide the glyphicon from all other users.

```
<% if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin") || Page.User.IsInRole("SysAdmin"))
   { %>
   <li id="liAdmin">
     <a runat="server" href="~/Admin/Admin.aspx">
        <span class="fa fa-wrench"> </span>
     </a>
   </li>
<% } %>
```

This works as expected when browsing to the http site, however when browsing to the https site the glyphicon will only appear for the Admin or SysAdmin users on the homepage of the website and is hidden when browsing to any other pages within the website. If you return to the homepage of the site the glyphicon does not re-appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing cacheRolesInCookie="true" to cacheRolesInCookie="false" in my web.config has resolved this one.

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="sqlProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" cookieName=".ASPROLES" cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="true" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
   <providers>
      <add name="sqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="users_db" applicationName="ReportingSystem" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```